# How do I generate SVG qrcode with image?

Tags: php

I have a code for generating qrcode in jpeg and png format but want to also generate svg qrcode with background image in PHP. I am using qrlib.php for generating jpeg and png format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

QRlib.php also does support SVG, doesn't it?

https://github.com/t0k4rt/phpqrcode

```
require_once(__DIR__.'/phpqrcode-master/qrlib.php');
echo QRcode::svg('hello');
```

Comment: I tried this but error occur called:
Fatal error: Call to undefined QRcode::svg()

Comment: Did you use the version from github linked above?

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is quite simple: as it seems to me there is a wrong build to download from the original source (= http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpqrcode/files/releases/). I tried this one and it didnt work for me either. On the other hand this source works: https://github.com/t0k4rt/phpqrcode
Hope this helps.
Uwe

Answer (score -2):

A **super hacky** solution is to embed the base64 encoded png image in your SVG File:

```
<image width="100" height="100" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,...">
```

Here's a complete sample SVG file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   width="200"
   height="200"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1">
<image width="200" height="200"
  xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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" />
</svg>
```

Comment: This completely defeats the purpose of using SVG since it's embedding PNG image inside of it. You might as well just use PNG right away. Scaling this kind of image will make it blurry.