# Error generating SVG with phpqrcode

Tags: php, svg, qr-code

I am trying to execute following code from the [SVG basic output example](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/examples/index.php?example=201) from the docs.

```
<?php
include('vendors/phpqrcode/qrlib.php');
$svgCode = QRcode::svg('PHP QR Code :)');
echo $svgCode;
```

All I get is the error:

> **Fatal error:** Call to undefined method QRcode::svg()
>
> /path/to/php/file/index.php on line 1337

The strange thing is that the simple PNG output example works fine without any errors, so the include must be correct.

```
<?php
include('vendors/phpqrcode/qrlib.php');
QRcode::png('PHP QR Code :)');
```

Do you guys have an idea what I might have forgot to check? Maybe the error is obvious for you.

Comment: are you using composer?(use of vendors) if so it will be `\PHPQRCode\QRcode::png()`, and *dont* use the include..

Comment: The last update to that library was four years ago, and it's hosted on SourceForge. IMO, those are two good signs it's time to find another library. https://packagist.org/packages/endroid/qrcode is one I've worked with.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I am not using composer. But thank you for this idea.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thank you. I will give this library a try! =)

Comment: You should strongly consider using Composer going forwards. Glad I could help.

Comment: @ceejayoz Since I am forced to use php version 5.4, endroid/qrcode is sadly not an option for me. I have not found another working library for 5.4.

Comment: You **need** to get off PHP 5.4. It has been unsupported for nearly two years and is likely to contain unpatched security holes as a result. It is dangerously insecure to run. http://php.net/eol.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noticed in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328022/how-do-i-generate-svg-qrcode-with-image) and I experienced myself, the latest version is at https://github.com/t0k4rt/phpqrcode. With the version there, SVG is implemented and working.